# jquery sibiling child link text

Tags: jquery, traversal

I'm trying to get the text from a child link of a sibling of an element.

```
<p>
  <a>This text here</a>
</p>
<form></form>
<ul></ul>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$('ul').each(function(){
  var theText = $(this).siblings('p a').text();
  console.log(theText);
})
```

I'm trying to do this without using prev or next.

Comment: change `$(this).siblings('p a').text();` to `$(this).siblings('p').children('a').text();`   [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PY2T6/) example

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('ul').each(function(){
  var theText = $(this).siblings().find('a').text();
  console.log(theText);
})
```

OR

@Satpal Comment

```
$('ul').each(function(){
      var theText = $(this).siblings('p').text();
      console.log(theText);
    })
```

[DEM0](http://jsfiddle.net/WwvCP/1/)

Comment: just a suggestion `siblings('p')` would be better

Comment: Thanks that works. I went with this combined with Satpal's answer. Cheers!